# What does the phrase "put down" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This context is from the movie "The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo"

Person speaking is describing an accident that happened years ago during a family gathering. It was a car accident near the house where the family gathered and they ran to help the victims.

It was chaos as everyone **put down**  what they were doing.

In the movie, he says **put down** but I always paste the context from a movie's script I find online and there the word "dropped" is used instead.

Two definitions I found for "put down" I found:

def 1 To bring to an end; repress: put down a **rebellion**.
(source Thefreedictionary)

def 2 verb To stop engaging with some piece of media or technology that requires the use of one's hands. (source Thefreedictionary)

The problem is that the family in the movie wasn't reading on engaging in any pieces of media or technology(they were just standing and holding their drinks) and definition 1 seems unlikely as well because every dictionary I found lists the example-sentence with **the Rebellion**

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from starting to consult different dictionaries; this is the second time TheFreeDictionary has given an example too narrow to be a working definition. You could "stop engaging with" other things besides media; cooks, musicians, and carpenters could all "put down what they're doing," even if they're holding whisks, guitars, or hammers.

Most importantly, the phrase can be used figuratively of things that aren't *held*. As you noted, "drop what you're doing" can be used almost interchangeably, but this one is even more ready to be used even if there is nothing physical to drop. A dance could "drop what he's doing" by stopping dancing. If you want someone to stop arguing with you you can say "drop it." In this sense, "everyone put down what they were doing" doesn't necessarily guarantee that everyone had something in their hands.

Answer (score 0):

To **put down what you are doing** signifies that you stop doing whatever you are busy with, placing on a table/chair/floor any items that may be in your hands.

Typically, the expression is used when something alarming/disturbing/fascinating interrupts whatever people are doing/holding - whether sewing, knitting, woodwork, books, drinks, eating - or whatever.

They stop doing whatever they are busy with in order to give their attention to something or somebody else.

The other meanings of the expression are not relevant here.

As you say, one can put down (suppress) a rebellion/uprising.

And people of speak of putting down (euthanising) an animal/pet that is injured, old and incapable or seriously ill.